# What are the actual names associated with each of the colours in "Among Us"?

Tags: among-us

When I first started playing *"Among Us"*, the colours were pretty generic. It was pretty easy to tell players apart, because they would be completely different colours like green or yellow.

You would still see the odd player call out "green" because they saw light green vent, only to correctly identify that it was lime and not the darker green after we vented the wrong one. It was uncommon, and even when it did happen it was easy to correct.

Now, *"Among Us"* supports up to fifteen players - and part of that includes having added a whole new set of colours. A lot of these colours look very similar - for example, there are three different colours that are all variations of pink. I find it a lot more common for a player to shout out "pink just killed in front of me", and for us to spend the next several rounds second guessing and trying to work out exactly what "pink" they actually saw.

[image]

What are the actual names associated with each of the colours in *"Among Us"*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]

Going along each row, from left to right, the colours are as follows:

- **Red**: One of the original colours.
- **Blue**: One of the original colours.
- **Green**: One of the original colours.
- **Pink**: One of the original colours.
- **Orange**: One of the original colours.
- **Yellow**: One of the original colours.
- **Black**: One of the original colours.
- **White**: One of the original colours.
- **Purple**: One of the original colours.
- **Brown**: One of the original colours.
- **Cyan**: One of the original colours. Sometimes called out as "light blue".
- **Lime**: One of the original colours. Sometimes called out as "light green"
- **Maroon**: A new colour. Distinct from red and coral, as it is much darker.
- **Rose**: A new colour. Rose is the lighter version of pink, and sits roughly in the middle of red and pink on the colour scale.
- **Banana**: A new colour. Banana is the lighter version of yellow, and takes its namesake from the colour of the inside of a banana. This one still causes a lot of confusion, so it might be worth double checking that someone means the "light" yellow, when they call out this colour.
- **Grey**: A new colour. Grey is half way between black and white; but don't get it confused with tan, as they can look very similar in the heat of the moment.
- **Tan**: A new colour. Tan is a lighter variant of brown; but it does not show the brown as much as other lighter colour variants.
- **Coral**: A new colour. Coral is a mix of red and orange.

These colour names have derived from observations over hundreds and hundreds of games, with supplemental information that I confirmed in game from the [Among Us wiki](https://among-us.fandom.com/wiki/Colors#List_of_Colors).

Comment: Is there an official source, or are these just the names that you gave to these colours?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I assume these are from in-game. The medical scan shows the colour names, for example.

Comment: Here's a link to the referenced page on the wiki: https://among-us.fandom.com/wiki/Colors

Comment: The untranslated names for the colors (taken from the code posted by ForteBass on Discord) are: ColorRed, ColorBlue, ColorGreen, ColorPink, ColorOrange, ColorYellow, ColorBlack, ColorWhite, ColorPurple, ColorBrown, ColorCyan, ColorLime, ColorMaroon, ColorRose, ColorBanana, ColorGray, ColorTan, and ColorCoral